# Why do electrical devices energized with alternating current make sound?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, acoustics

I was recently trying to study, when I became aware that a nearby fluorescent bulb was humming. Because of this, I began thinking about sound from electrical components. In the past I've assembled crystal radios from those "snap together" kits, and I once connected a DC motor in place of the speaker in the name of experimentation. The motor functioned surprisingly well as a quiet speaker.

They may be due to different principles, but why would a plain DC motor function as a speaker, and why do florescent bulbs hum?

Comment: You should try this with a modified sine wave from an inverter that goes to your car. You will get even more noise.

Comment: Quick research suggests a simpler answer to the fluorescent bulb thing than I expected. Haven't found anything interesting about DC motors though. I'll edit my question when I can.

Comment: [Here's the Wikipedia page on this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_excited_acoustic_noise_and_vibration)

Comment: @SamGallagher That's quite the interesting article. Thanks for sharing! I'm not sure I would have guess that Wikipedia might have a page on this.

Answer (score 2):

You know that sound are mechanical waves that propagate through the air (or solids or liquid, but the sound that we hear reaches our ears through the air).

On the other hand, any object immersed in air that moves will move the air around it in a manner that is related to its own movement. This movement of air is nothing else than sound waves (you may not hear them if they are at low frequencies or low intensity, but they exist). So if you manage to move any object that is immersed in air in a certain way, you will produce sound.

In the case of the fluorescent tubes the "object immersed in air" is the [ballast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_ballast) that is present in every (old) tube, and the force that makes it move to produce a 50 or 60 Hz sound is due to the magnetic field it creates because of the alternating current flowing through it. This alternating current, as its name suggests, alternates at a frequency of 50 or 60 Hz (in most countries) so the resulting "movement of the object immersed in air" has this same frequency, and so does the sound produced.If you have a piano you can check the [note of the sound](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frecuencias_de_afinaci%C3%B3n_del_piano). It should be near a G for a 50 Hz country and near a B for a 60 Hz country.

For the case of a speaker, the "object immersed in sound" is the cone of the speaker and it is specially designed to obtain the greatest possible movement using the lowest possible electrical signal (well, this is not the only thing that we want in a speaker, but roughly speaking it is). In this case the force that moves the cone of the speaker is, again, due to a magnetic field produced by the coil inside the speaker.

If you replace the speaker with a DC motor, the rotor will be the "object immersed in air" and will feel a force in the same way as the speaker, due to the magnetic field produced by the coils of the motor. It will not spin because the audio signal of the radio has no DC component, and you wont be able to see it moving because it will surely a very small movement. But it will move enough to produce a sound (probably with much less intensity that the speaker).

Comment: But I'm still not sure I see why the motor rotor would produce sound. The magnetic field in a speaker causes a linear displacement of the speaker cone, while the field in the motor causes a rotation. In the case of the speaker, it's the cone that is causing minute pneumatic shockwaves. What part of a symmetrical rod would have the same effect?

Comment: Are you suggesting that perhaps the rotor coil itself is rotating forward and back in a manner similar to the linear motion of the speaker cone?

Comment: The rotor is not a perfect cylinder, inside the case of the motor it has a very complex shape with magnets or coils that can perfectly displace the air to produce the sound. In fact if you attach a fan to the rotor it will probably sound louder (it has to be a very light fan, if it is heavy then you can have the opposed effect as the rotor will move less).

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified my comment. I've disassembled DC motors before, so I know they're not perfect cylinders. I was asking whether it's the oscillating rotation as opposed to oscillating linear motion that's causing the effect. Reading your latest comment, however, I can see that was indeed what you were suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Many AC powered devices use magnetics---coils of wire wrapped around iron cores.  Electric motors, anything with a transformer in it, magnetic ballasts in HID light fixtures and older fluorescent light fixtures, etc.

All of the above can produce noise at some multiple of the power line frequency via [magnetostriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostriction).